# Google App Engine GAE Php send attachment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email, yaml, email-attachments

Hello I'm trying to add a few attachments to my app in Google app engine. I send the email and get the body as well as the subject but for some reason the attachments don't come through and googles method of explaining it doesn't really do it any justice.

here is my app.yaml file

```
application: 'phpmail' 
version: 1
runtime:php
api_version:1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
-url: /favicon\.ico
static_files: favicon.ico
upload: favicon\.ico

-url: .*
script:main.php
```

and here is the main.php file

```
<html>
<head> 
other info I have
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';

use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

// ...

$message_body = "...";

$mail_options = [
"sender" => "sender@gmail.com",
"to" => "reciever@yahoo.com",
"cc" => "reciever@aol.com",
"subject" => "Your account has been activatedd",
"textBody" => "Guten tag, here is an email, with hopefully two attachments",
];
image= open('./file1.png', 'file2.jpg')
        message.attachments=[(file1.png, file2.jpg())]
        image.close()
try {
  $message = new Message($mail_options);
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
echo $e;
  }
{
   echo "Your message has been sent";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the code you added even executes. Anyway, here's a way to do it.

```
$subject = uniqid();
$content = "Hello, world!";

$message = new Message();
$from = createMailAddress();
$message->setSender($from);
$to = createMailAddress();
$message->addTo($to);
$message->setTextBody($content);
$message->setSubject($subject);
$message->addAttachment('data.txt', 'Here is some text as an attachment');
$message->send();
```

Comment: Thank you that enabled me to send attachments, however I can't actually view them in my mail provider and when I download them preview says "the file "file.png" could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that preview doesn't recognize. 
- url: /images/(file.jpg)
  static_files /images/\1
  upload: /images/file.jpg

I made some changes to app.yaml file above also thinking that might fix it, but to no avail. I feel like i'm close but just can't get there. Do i need to add any mime type of code too?